# Objective c runtime method creation and subclassing limits

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

I was trying to create a subclass of the class `WFAirportViewController` in the new WiFiKitUI private framework for iOS 11 during runtime. The class is used as the interface of the wifi connection scene in the settings app. My intention is to create a subclass so that I can keep all the functionality and change up the looks of the views. That didn't work as I try to execute the code it just crashes. Then I tried to create a new method for the class with `class_addMethod`, it returned false meaning that the method creation wasn't successful, but when I tried to get the class in runtime with `objc_getClass` it did work so it means that the class is retrievable. Is there some kind of restriction for runtime subclassing and method creation that is not documented because I have searched for a while now and nothing shows up.

Comment: If I understand the question, you created a subclass, added some code to it, and upon running that code encountered a crash.  From that crash you concluded that you couldn't create a subclass?  Have you considered the possibility that it is the code (not the fact that it is  added to a subclass) that's the problem?

Comment: The line that caused the crash was `objc_allocateClassPair()` which was used to create the subclass. after deleting that line of code the program worked fine. Also the subclass I created was empty so it only had empty methods that does nothing